# NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of eqns in the first argument eqns

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica, actually, I am working on a project based on Swarm Intelligence. I am trying to run a simulation of sphere formation of 10 robots, but there is a problem in equations. Here is my code:

```
In[27]:= ClearAll["Global`*"] (*Clear all variables and definitions*)
numofbots = 20;
(*Number of agents*)dim = 2;
(*Dimension*)totaltime = 100;
(*Total time to simulate for*)
initpos = RandomReal[{1, 1.5}, {numofbots, dim}];
(*Initial positions,generated randomly*)
initvel = RandomReal[{-.1, 0.1}, {numofbots, dim}];
(*Initial velocities,generated randomly*)
sphereRadius = 3;
(*Distance function-depends on the metric tensor,and difficult to calculate in general*)
dist[pos1_, pos2_] := 
sphereRadius*
  ArcCos[Sin[pos1[[2]]]*Sin[pos2[[2]]] +                                        
Cos[pos1[[2]]]*Cos[pos2[[2]]]*Cos[pos1[[1]] - pos2[[1]]]]
u[pos1_, pos2_] := 
 dist[pos1,pos2]^2;(*Potential function,based on distance function*)
 g ={{sphereRadius^2*Cos[x[2]]^2, 0}, {0, sphereRadius^2}};
(*Metric tensor for spherical surface*)
ginv = Inverse[g];
(*Inverse of the metric tensor*)
christoffel[a_, i_, j_] := 
 1 / 2*Sum[Inverse[g][[a]][[k]]*(D[g[[i, k]], x[j]] + 
  D[g[[j, k]], x[i]] - D[g[[i, j]], x[k]]), {k, 2}];
(*Christoffel symbols for the space*)


    In[33]:=eqns = Table[
  With[{i = i}, {Table[r[i][j]'[t] == v[i][j][t], {j, dim}], 
    Table[v[i][j]'[
       t] == (1 - 
          Sum[v[i][k][t]*
            v[i][l][
             t]*(g[[k, l]] /. 
              Table[x[ii] -> r[i][ii][t], {ii, dim}]), {k, 
            dim}, {l, dim}])*v[i][j][t] - 
       1 / numofbots*
        Sum[Sum[(ginv[[j, jj]] /. 
             Table[x[ii] -> r[i][ii][t], {ii, dim}])*
           D[u[Table[r[i][k][t], {k, dim}], 
             Table[r[ii][k][t], {k, dim}]], r[i][jj][t]], {jj, 
           dim}], {ii, numofbots}] - 
       Sum[(christoffel[j, k, l] /. 
           Table[x[jj] -> r[i][jj][t], {jj, dim}])*v[i][k][t]*
         v[i][l][t], {k, dim}, {l, dim}], {j, dim}], 
    Table[r[i][j][0] == initpos[[i]][[j]], {j, dim}], 
    Table[v[i][j][0] == initvel[[i]][[j]], {j, dim}]
    }], {i, numofbots}];(*Equations for the model*)
unknownFun = Table[r[i][j], {i, numofbots}, {j, dim}];
(*unknowns for the model:positions of each agent*)


In[33]:=sol = First@NDSolve[eqns, unknownFun, {t, 0, totaltime}, 
    "Method" -> {"EquationSimplification" ->
      {Automatic, "TimeConstraint" -> 10}}];
(*Solve the diff eq*)
swarmpos = unknownFun /. sol;
(*calculate the unknowns given the solution*)

In[35]:=project[vec_] := {Cos[vec[[2]]]*Cos[vec[[1]]], 
   Cos[vec[[2]]]*Sin[vec[[1]]], Sin[vec[[2]]]};
(*Define projection onto spherical surface*)

funddom[t_] := 
  Show[{Graphics[
     Table[Point[Table[swarmpos[[i]][[j]][t], {j, dim}]], {i, 
       numofbots}], 
     PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, 
     Axes -> True]}];
(*Define animation on fundamental domain*)

manif[t_] := 
 Show[{Graphics3D[{Sphere[], 
     Table[Point[project[Table[swarmpos[[i]][[j]][t], {j, dim}]]], {i,
        numofbots}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large]}]
(*Define animation on spherical surface*)
Animate[
 GraphicsGrid[{{funddom[t], manif[t]}}], {t, 0, totaltime}]
(*Display both animations side-by-side*)
```

This simulation is taken from a paper published by **UNITED STATES NAVAL ACADEMY
ANNAPOLIS, MARYLAND** and its title is:

> [Stability of Nonlinear Swarms on Flat and Curved Surfaces.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_MzbUhKXtqVnUuTKQ8mMGVtKEoAq97ly/view?usp=sharing)

This paper contains a lot of detail on swarm and also it contains a technical implementation of swarm in ROS Gazebo.
For more detail on swarm read the paper mentioned above.
I am using Wolfram Mathematica 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several typos in this code. After fixing, the code works and creates an animation

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] (*Clear all variables and definitions*)
numofbots = 20;
(*Number of agents*)dim = 2;
(*Dimension*)totaltime = 100;
(*Total time to simulate for*)
initpos = RandomReal[{1, 1.5}, {numofbots, dim}];
(*Initial positions,generated randomly*)
initvel = RandomReal[{-.1, 0.1}, {numofbots, dim}];
(*Initial velocities,generated randomly*)
sphereRadius = 3;
(*Distance function-depends on the metric tensor,and difficult to \
calculate in general*)
dist[pos1_, pos2_] := 
 sphereRadius*
  ArcCos[Sin[pos1[[2]]]*Sin[pos2[[2]]] + 
    Cos[pos1[[2]]]*Cos[pos2[[2]]]*Cos[pos1[[1]] - pos2[[1]]]]
u[pos1_, pos2_] := 
 dist[pos1, 
   pos2]^2;(*Potential function,based on distance function*)g = \
{{sphereRadius^2*Cos[x[2]]^2, 0}, {0, sphereRadius^2}};
(*Metric tensor for spherical surface*)
ginv = Inverse[g];
(*Inverse of the metric tensor*)
christoffel[a_, i_, j_] := 
  1/2*Sum[Inverse[g][[a, k]]*(D[g[[i, k]], x[j]] + 
       D[g[[j, k]], x[i]] - D[g[[i, j]], x[k]]), {k, 2}];
(*Christoffel symbols for the space*)
(*Display both animations side-by-side*)

eqns = Table[
  With[{i = i}, {Table[r[i][j]'[t] == v[i][j][t], {j, dim}], 
    Table[v[i][j]'[
       t] == (1 - 
          Sum[v[i][k][t]*
            v[i][l][
             t]*(g[[k, l]] /. 
              Table[x[ii] -> r[i][ii][t], {ii, dim}]), {k, dim}, {l, 
            dim}])*v[i][j][t] - 
       1/numofbots*
        Sum[Sum[(ginv[[j, jj]] /. 
             Table[x[ii] -> r[i][ii][t], {ii, dim}])*
           D[u[Table[r[i][k][t], {k, dim}], 
             Table[r[ii][k][t], {k, dim}]], r[i][jj][t]], {jj, 
           dim}], {ii, numofbots}] - 
       Sum[(christoffel[j, k, l] /. 
           Table[x[jj] -> r[i][jj][t], {jj, dim}])*v[i][k][t]*
         v[i][l][t], {k, dim}, {l, dim}], {j, dim}], 
    Table[r[i][j][0] == initpos[[i]][[j]], {j, dim}], 
    Table[v[i][j][0] == initvel[[i]][[j]], {j, dim}]}], {i, 
   numofbots}];(*Equations for the model*)unknownFun = 
 Table[r[i][j], {i, numofbots}, {j, dim}];
(*unknowns for the model:positions of each agent*)

sol = First@
   NDSolve[eqns, unknownFun, {t, 0, totaltime}, 
    "Method" -> {"EquationSimplification" -> {Automatic, 
        "TimeConstraint" -> 10}}];
(*Solve the diff eq*)
swarmpos = unknownFun /. sol;
(*calculate the unknowns given the solution*)

project[vec_] := {Cos[vec[[2]]]*Cos[vec[[1]]], 
   Cos[vec[[2]]]*Sin[vec[[1]]], Sin[vec[[2]]]};
(*Define projection onto spherical surface*)

funddom[t_] := 
  Show[{Graphics[
     Table[Point[Table[swarmpos[[i]][[j]][t], {j, dim}]], {i, 
       numofbots}], PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, 
     Axes -> True]}];
(*Define animation on fundamental domain*)

manif[t_] := 
 Show[{Graphics3D[{Sphere[], 
     Table[Point[project[Table[swarmpos[[i]][[j]][t], {j, dim}]]], {i,
        numofbots}]}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large]}]
(*Define animation on spherical surface*)


Animate[GraphicsGrid[{{funddom[t], manif[t]}}], {t, 0, totaltime}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Comment: @danyialKhan you're welcome!